# Unable to install openssl for python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I can't install any `pyopenssl` on python. I've tried to install it with `pip install pyopenssl` but it still doesn't work.
I have tried to use:

```
python -m pip install pyopenssl
```

But when I check if the module has been installed, I get that it has been not.
By the way, for checking if the module is installed I am using a `try-except` block.

```py
try:
    import pyopenssl 
    print('\nModule was installed')
except ImportError:
    print('\nThere was no such module installed')
```

Comment: so you install python and pip yourself, do you use anaconda, and do you use virtualenv

Comment: What is the OS type you are using?

Comment: I don't know what is anaconda and I don't know what is virtualenv. I don't use them

Comment: And the OS I'm using is windows 10